# In mini-batch learning, inputs for Fully Connected Layer is 1 or 2 dim?

Tags: python, pytorch

In mini-batch learning, is the input a 1D array with no distinction between mini batches? Or is it a 2-dimensional array with mini batches and data?

Specifically, I would like to know how to input testdata, torch.Size([batch_size=20, height=256, width=256]) minibatch into the fully connected layer.

Now mycode

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, 128)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, out_features)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)       
        x = self.relu(x)
        out = self.fc2(x)



# input:torch.Size([batch_size=20, height=256, width=256]) 
model = Net(20*256*256, 20*256*256)

input = torch.flatten(input)
output = model(input)
output = torch.reshape(output, (20, 256, 256))
```

(Never mind there is no conv layer.)

I am not sure if it is appropriate.
Can anyone teach me?

Comment: Can you share your entire code so that your issue could be replicated? Or at least, a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. 
I have described the code in detail and **fixed** some inconsistencies. I'm sorry for the past confusion...  // 
The error I wrote about before was due to a poorly defined Net, and I have removed it from the question as it resolved itself.
 // 
**However, I still don't understand the question I mentioned in the title.** So if you could answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: sorry for the many edits of my answer but now I think it covers everything, include your title question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: the input to a fully connected layer is a tensor of any number of dimensions, provided the last dimension's size matches the number of input features of the fully connected layer

There are some issues with your code.

First, don't use the word `input`. `Input()` is built-in python function.
Instead, create a torch tensor and pass it to your model:

```
input_tensor = torch.randn((20, 256, 256)).flatten()
model = Net(256*256,256*256)
output_tensor = model(input_tensor)
output_tensor = torch.reshape(output_tensor, (BATCH_SIZE, IMG_VER, IMG_HOR))
```

Second, the number of input and output features of a fully connected layer should **not** include the batch size. That is,

```
model = Net(256*256, 256*256)
```

instead of

```
model = Net(20*256*256, 20*256*256)
```

Third, it's best not to assume that whoever uses your model knows that they
need to change it's shape. Instead, change the shape inside the model.
And fourth, the `forward()` function should return it's output. See this:

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, 128)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, out_features)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x.reshape((20, -1))
        x = self.relu(x)
        out = self.fc2(x)
        return out


model = Net(256*256, 256*256)
input_tensor = torch.randn((20, 256, 256))
output_tensor = model(input_tensor)
```

Comment: Thank you for your instruction, it was an error due to trying to generalize from the original code... // 
As for the title of the question, am I correct in understanding that the entire batch can be one-dimensional, as the respondent wrote?

Comment: No. it would be wrong to flatten the entire batch. You wan your model to calculate an output for each item in your batch. Flattening the entire batch into a single 1-D vector and changing the input features to match will cause your model to calculate an output for all items in the batch at once.

Comment: @modu01 You're most welcome. If you found my answer useful, I would appreciate if you upvoted it in addition to accepting.

Comment: I see, x.reshape((20, -1)) is the key... It makes sense in terms of my imagine, and this is learned a lot. Thanks for your time!